# How to parse YAML file in Java8 and SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I have the below YAML file:

```
customers:
  UniqueProductName1:
    SubscriptionPlan1:
      User1: {payment:150, limit: 200}
      User2: {payment:200, limit: 300}
      User3: {payment:60, limit: 100}
    SubscriptionPlan2:
      User1: {payment:150, limit: 200}
      User2: {payment:200, limit: 300}
      User5: {payment:150, limit: 200}
  UniqueProductName2:
    SubscriptionPlan1:
      User6: {payment:150, limit: 200}
      User7: {payment:200, limit: 300}
      User4: {payment:60, limit: 100}
    SubscriptionPlan2:
      User5: {payment:150, limit: 200}
      User8: {payment:200, limit: 300}
      User9: {payment:150, limit: 200}
    SubscriptionPlan3:
      User5: {payment:150, limit: 200}
      User8: {payment:200, limit: 300}
      User10: {payment:150, limit: 200}
```

How can I get the value of `UniqueProductName1.SubscriptionPlan1.User3.payment`?
There are no fields describing the content like UniqueProductName1 is a "product", etc in this yaml file content

I tried using jackson jar:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I created the below Java beans:

MainYaml.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("customers")
public class MainYaml {

    public List<CustomerProduct> customerProductList;

    //getter and setter
```

CustomerProduct.java: (Do I need to use @configurationproperties annotation here as well?)

```
public class CustomerProduct{
    public String productName;
    public List<CustomerPlan> customerPlansList;

    //getter and setter
```

CustomerPlan.java:

```
public class CustomerPlan{
    public String planName;
    public List<Customer> customerList;

    //getter and setter
```

Customer.java:

```
@Component
public class Customer{
    public String customerName;

    public CustomerDetail customerDetail ;

    //getter and setter
```

CustomerDetail.java:

```
public class CustomerDetail {

@JsonProperty
public String payment;

@JsonProperty
public String limit;
```

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to parse this kind of yaml file in Java?

Comment: Use a YAML library.

Comment: I'm not sure if data for your Userx could be parsed with yaml, but try to read [here](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation)